# Dealing with iOS and Android diferences on xamarin.forms

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im building a cross platform app. I have just finished my prototype and it works well on android. However, i started testing the prototype on iOS and i am getting some problems that i dont know how to solve and i wish you guys can help me.

So, for now i have 2 problems:
1st > On android button inside listview is recognizing its event handler/command and firing the event. But on iPhone, its being ignored.

2nd > IPhone seems to be adding some icons to my view that didnt apear on android and they have no utility for me. Is there any way to remove them ?

Xaml:

```
                   <local:CustomListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:CustomViewCell>
                                <ContentView Padding="10,10,10,0">
                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding Cor}" CornerRadius="5">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Image="{Binding ImageSource}" Rotation="90" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                         CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding BindingContext.CommandoOpcoes, Source={x:Reference tarefas}}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Scale="0.7" Source="{local:ImageResource x.Images.location1.png}"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Titulo}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Scale="0.7" Source="{local:ImageResource x.Images.clock.png}"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Duracao}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Scale="0.7" Source="{local:ImageResource x.Images.location2.png}"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding ObjectivoAno}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ContentView>
```

View Model :

```
        public Command CommandoOpcoes
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /*
            * Menu de um item da lista clicado
            * Apresenta opções de editar, apagar e marcar uma tarefa como concluída
        */
        private void MostraOpcoes(object t)
        {
            var Tarefa = t as Tarefa;

            async void apagarTarefa()
            {
                var res = await App.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(AppResource.Confirmacao, AppResource.Apagar, AppResource.Nao, AppResource.Sim);

                if (res == false)
                {
                    Tarefas.Remove(Tarefa);
                    NTarefas--;
                }
            }

            async void editarTarefa()
            {
                var page = new EditarTarefa()
                {
                    BindingContext = Tarefa
                };
                if (PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Count > 0)
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync(false);
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page, true);
            }

            void completarTarefa()
            {
                if (Tarefa.Cumprido == false)
                {
                    Tarefa.Cumprido = true;
                    Tarefa.Cor = Color.FromHex("#E5F2E5");
                    NTarefasConcluidos++;
                    if (NTarefasNaoConcluidos > 0)
                        NTarefasNaoConcluidos--;
                }
                else
                {
                    Tarefa.Cumprido = false;
                    Tarefa.Cor = Color.FromHex("#FFE5E5");
                    NTarefasNaoConcluidos++;
                    if (NTarefasConcluidos > 0)
                        NTarefasConcluidos--;
                }
            }

            ActionSheetConfig config = new ActionSheetConfig();



            if (Tarefa.Cumprido)
                config.Add(AppResource.nCompleto, completarTarefa, "completo.png");
            else
            {
                config.Add(AppResource.EditarTarefa, editarTarefa, "edit.png");
                config.Add(AppResource.Completo, completarTarefa, "completo.png");
            }

            config.SetDestructive(AppResource.ApagarTarefa, apagarTarefa, "delete.png");

            config.UseBottomSheet = true;
            UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheet(config).Dispose();
            UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheet(config);
        }

        public TarefasViewModel()
        {
            Tarefas = new ObservableCollection<Tarefa>(App.tarefas.Where(x => x.Data == DateTime.Today).ToList());
            NTarefas = Tarefas.Count;
            NTarefasConcluidos = Tarefas.Where(x => x.Cumprido == true).Count();
            NTarefasNaoConcluidos = Tarefas.Where(x => x.Cumprido == false).Count();
            CommandoOpcoes = new Command(q => MostraOpcoes(q));
        }
```

Image of view on iOS with the undesired icons : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS62D.jpg

Image on android : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltrvH.jpg

Comment: extra arrow in iOS is DisclosureIndicator. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/customizing-table-appearance. for better explanation

Comment: may be you have to make some changes in your CustomListView

Comment: Have you defined a custom renderer for your list view on iOS? The default appearance for list view doesn't contain the disclosure indicator on the right side of view cell. Maybe, it was that accessory which disables your button's command. Could you please share a sample so that we could help you look into your issues?

Comment: Sample of the custom listview ? @LandLu-MSFT you mean code or image?

Comment: @Kelve Yes, a sample for your list view which can reproduce your issue on my side.

Comment: alright. give me 5 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found the solution. It was quite easy.On ViewCell, the StyleId property can add disclosure buttons to iOS lists.
To not have any of these disclosure buttons, i just made :

```
<ViewCell StyeleId="none">...</ViewCell>
```